# How do I connect to a SQL Server database from Power BI?

Tags: sql-server, database, view, powerbi, visualization

I created some views in SQL Server and would like to use them for visualization in Power BI. Currently, I am trying to connect my Power BI to SQL Server. I keep getting an error in Power BI just after entering the server name. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

My SQL Server name:

[image: My SQL server Name]

Entering server into PowerBI: I tried `DESKTOP-63CGS35\SQLEXPRESS` as the username, it didn't work as well.

[image]

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you’ve elected to use your username in an input field that is asking for the Server? How did you reach the conclusion that these are the same?

Answer (score 2):

"DESKTOP-63CGS35\SQLEXPRESS" is the server and instance name and that's what goes in the "Server" field on the Power BI connection dialog.

Comment: Yes. I tried this as well and it did not work.